# Making PHP code shorter

Tags: php

I have found that writing PHP code within classes can become rather long:

```
$this->parser->parse_syntax($this->get_language_path($this->language),
                                    $this->elements,
                                    $this->regex);
```

For example, in Java a class instance can call its methods by name without referencing **this**, is there a way to achieve shorter code in PHP without using this and self every time you have to read a value?

Comment: HDD space is cheap in 2011.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the kilobytes used up on my hdd, but the effort it takes to achieve something in PHP code. Unfortunately, we aren't as fast as computers when it comes to processing code :)

Comment: You can shorten get_language_path to glp. On a more serious note, you have to refer to the calling object.

Comment: So apart from shortening my variables, there's no real way of reducing the length of this code. Because when I look at it, it's not doing anything particularly difficult, just passing variables. I may be a bit pedantic here, but as you can see I've had to use three lines for this simple method call.

Comment: Perhaps define a keyboard macro for `$this->` in your code editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in PHP if you want to run object's method or read/write property from inside of object you must write `$this` to refer that object instance.

PS. You can do at the beginning of each method something like this: `$s = $this` and use `$s` then, but it's **strongly unrecommended**, you **shouldn't do that** and it will be best, if you forget that you read this paragraph :)

Comment: Haha, ok that is a neat trick nonetheless, I was also thinking of declaring local instances of a class' variables, such as: $code = &$this->code; and using $code instead.

Comment: @Aram Kocharyan: this trick will increase the difficulty of the code. It will be harder to read, harder to maintain and easier to make a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was afraid it could cause ambiguity.

Comment: If I found code that used any of these "brevity" tricks at work, I would find the developer responsible and smack them with a mackerel. Seriously, don't do this!

Answer (score 3):

I think it all comes down to your data structure, for instance your `parse_syntax()` method can default to `$this->elements` and `$this->regex` if null is passed instead:

```
class foo
{
    public $parser = null;
    public $language = null;
    public $elements = null;
    public $regex = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->parser = new parser();
    }

    public function get_language_path($language = null)
    {
        $language = (isset($language)) ? $language : $this->language;

        // your code here
    }
}

class parser extends foo
{
    public function parse_syntax($path = null, $elements = null, $regex = null)
    {
        $path = (isset($path)) ? $path : parent::get_language_path();
        $elements = (isset($elements)) ? $elements : $this->elements;
        $regex = (isset($regex)) ? $regex : $this->regex;

        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the example, I didn't really mention it, but parser is another class instance stored as a property/variable in the class I'm working with. Rather than pass the variables from one class to another, would you say that passing $this as an argument and then reading the class' properties would be a cleaner way? I was concerned this might cause ambiguity as to what is actually changed by a method.

Comment: @Aram Kocharyan: Sorry for that, check my update. Also, better naming conventions would go a long way. Why `parser::parse_syntax` and not just `parse::syntax`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Java does not always need this, it also does not need the $ in front of variables, and you use just one dot (.) instead of -> to reference object's variable.

But Python is still shorter than Java - you don't need to use braces in Python, then use Python. 
Scala also much shorter than Java, so if you really need to write less code, then php is not the best choice.

Look into Python or Scala

Comment: Although Java doesn't always need `this`, I think it is a good practice to use it when accessing object properties or calling object methods. It's clearer to me.